# Are digital inputs of data acquisition devices differential or single ended?

Tags: signal-integrity

I read that in almost all daq board datasheets the analog inputs are specified as single ended or differential inputs.

But the same daq have digital I/O ports. How can one understand whether the digital input is differential ended or single-ended. Or are the default one of them?

For example from a manual:

> 16 single-ended (SE) or eight differential (DIFF) analog input
>   channels
>
> Eight individually configurable digital I/O channels

As you see the differential or single input nature of the analog inputs are specified. But for digital inputs no information.

How is CM noise for a digital signal rejected ?

Which one of the opamp represents digital input?:

[image]

Edit:

The black is the pulse waveform below, and the red is the noise superimposed on it. So if the system were diff ended and inputs were diff ended the red CM noise would be rejected. But for digital inputs red will never be rejected since it is swinging between the thresholds?:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There will be no single/differential end digital i/o 's

1. single end: Measure the voltage between the input signal and analog ground.
2. differential end: measure the voltage between two distinct input signals.

digital inputs will be either HIGH/LOW with respect to Ground

CM noise rejection:
actually lets say there is a bridge sensor. The sensor measurement of ADC is independent of the low level ground which makes it more free of noise. The reason for this is that the noise source is present on both signal leads and when in differential mode only the difference between the two leads is measured.

Regarding your both the images

first image is differential ended analog input

second one is single ended analog input

if a digital signal heve noise lets say, but 
[image]

it will receive that data as

[image]

since usually in most of

TTL cirucits

0 to 0.8V - LOW

2 V to VCC - LOW

if in cmos

0 to 1/3VCC - LOW

2/3 to VCC - HIGH

there is a lot of width b/w LOW and HIGH

Comment: How about RS485? Isnt that digital?

Comment: RS485 IS an communication standard. here i am giving information on digital and analog pins.

Comment: I see but the diff analog inputs are useful to reject CM noise as you know. Isnt there a similar way for the digital inputs?

Comment: I mean how is CM noise for a digital signal rejected ?

Comment: Differential analog inputs are mostly used to measure Bridge type of sensors and measuring a sensor value with reference to other

Comment: What kind of amplifier or opamps are used for digital inputs? Can you provide an example topology?

Comment: can you pls ask the question in detail?

Comment: Take the diff ended analog input for instance. By subtracting two inputs it rejects the CM noise. How is that CM rejection done for the digital inputs? Or there is no CM rejection?

Comment: actually lets say there is a bridge sensor. The sensor measurement of ADC is independent of the low level ground which makes it more free of noise. The reason for this is that the noise source is present on both signal leads and when in differential mode only the difference between the two leads is measured.

Comment: See my edited question. I provided two circuits. Which one represents the digital input?

Comment: there will be no digital single ended and digital differential inputs. Pls understand when we talk about digital signal either LOW OR HIGH

Comment: Im confused can you provide a topology how it looks like? So digital input will not reject a CM noise?

Comment: pls recheck the answer - i edited with again and update me

Comment: But what if the noise is as big as the amplitude of the pulse? So it will not work because it is more than the thresholds for LOW and HIGH. Strange that why there is no common mode rejection for digital inputs.

Comment: the cable pickup's will not be more.

Comment: See my last edit. The red is the noise. The input is a pulse with a CM noise(red one). The digital input will not reject that red noise?

Comment: can you share the hardware schematic with me for which you are getting that noise?

Comment: Im not getting anything it is conceptual question. I was wondering how digital inputs reject CM noise.

Comment: yeh got it. But in practice there will not be such a case..